# What is the order in which different functions are called in a Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to Windows Forms. This page on [Form Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx) lists exhaustively the methods, properties and events associated with the class. But what I would really like to know, to help understand forms better, is what is the flow of different methods on a form? Which method gets called when a page gets initialized upto which method gets called when the page is closed? When is [onActivated method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onactivated(v=vs.110).aspx) called and what does it do?

I hope you get my drift. Knowing an approximate flow of these methods would help understand existing codes in Windows Forms and writing them much easier. Would be great if you could point me to a suitable resource or shed some light on it.

EDIT: 
Turns out, it was documented afterall. Thanks juharr, and everyone else.

Comment: Did you see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: the link you posted *tells* you want they do; and when events are raised.

Comment: A GUI program is event driven.  The order in which methods run is therefore heavily affected by the order in which the events occur.  Plenty of those are fairly unpredictable, especially those coming from 3 feet in front of the monitor.

Comment: if my answer helpt you please regard it for the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is best detailed in **Order of Events in Windows Forms** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

The list below are some methods and events you may need, the complete list can be found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

- Form Constructor (It Calls InitializeComponents)
- Form_Load
- Form_Activated
- Form_Shown
- Form_Closing
- Form_Closed